# Callback from Dialog window to Main window

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, callback, mvvm-light

I'm developing a WPF MVVM application which make use of **MVVMLightToolkit** as a third party helper.My scenarion is as follows:

I have a main window and while closing the main window, I have to show a new dialog window(save changes dialog window) to confirm the user that, whether he has to **save** the changes that he made in the application to a state file or **not**. How can I handle this scenario in MVVM?. Normally for showing a new window, I'm making use of MVVMLight **Messenger** class.In that case, I'm opening the **Save Changes Dialog window** from **Main Window** code behind.I need a call back to the Main View model based on the selected user option(SAVE,SAVE/EXIT,CANCEL) from the Save Changes Dialog Window and based on that I have to check whether I have to close the main window or not. What would be the best MVVM approach to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass messages from/ to ViewModel.

**View**:

```cs
private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    Messenger.Default.Send(new WindowRequestsClosingMessage(
        this, 
        null,
        result => 
        { 
            if (!result)
                e.Cancel = true;
        });
}
```

**ViewModel**:

```cs
Messenger.Default.Register<WindowRequestsClosingMessage>(
    this,
    msg => 
    {

        // Your logic before close

        if (CanClose)
            msg.Execute(true);
        else
            msg.Execute(false);
    });
```

**Message**:

```cs
public class WindowRequestsClosingMessage: NotificationMessageAction<bool>
{
    public WindowRequestsClosingMessage(string notification, Action<bool> callback)
        : base(notification, callback)
    {
    }

    public WindowRequestsClosingMessage(object sender, string notification, Action<bool> callback)
        : base(sender, notification, callback)
    {
    }

    public WindowRequestsClosingMessage(object sender, object target, string notification, Action<bool> callback)
        : base(sender, target, notification, callback)
    {
    }
}
```

MVVM Light's *NotificationMessageAction<TResult>* allows you to pass a message and get a result of TResult type. To pass the TResult back to the requester, call `Execute()` just like the example.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you do something like the following in your Closing-Event:

```
    private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        SaveDialog sd = new SaveDialog();
        if (sd.ShowDialog() == false)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: SaveDialog.ShowDialog() returns a nullable bool value. My application is a WPF app not Windows.

Comment: So change `SaveDialogResults.Cancel` to true or false or null, whatever you want^^

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually the Window_Closing command is handled from ViewModel using RelayCommand. From that command handler, with the use of Messenger(MVVMLight) I'm showing the SaveChanges Dialog window from  main window code behind. I need a call back to main view model command handler and pass the selected option from Save Diallog window. Hope now you understand my situation.

Comment: Ok. I am not familiar with MVVMLight, but couldnt you just send a Message with Messenger to your ViewModel back, like `Messenger.Send<bool?, ViewModel>(SaveDialog.ShowDialog());` and Register for it through `Messenger.Register<bool?>(this, delegate(bool? result) { });`

Comment: I need a call back to Main Window Closing Command Handler method so that I can save the state. If I send a message from view to viewmodel as per your suggestion, I didn't get callback to  that method.